# Perl: pushing elements into array replaces existing value with new variable value

Tags: arrays, perl

I am reading a csv file and need to make values in a row(4th row) as the key elements in database. But the row contains multiple values comma separated.

1. I parsed the file with Text::CSV and split the values in 4th row.
2. Then push these values in an array and insert into a new file keeping other values same.
3. But in next run of loop and the value is replaced by the new value.
4. Hence I end up with as many instance of the last value in the array (2 in example below)

The code :

```
use Data::Dumper;
use strict;
my @oneRow = ('Vehicle Factory',
          'D3',
          '2518, 1613, 1512, 1109, 912 bus, 712 bus, 613 Export',
          'ajj137035, mgp657301',
          'ddb255570',
          'mdb650204'
          );
my $row = \@oneRow;
my @newRows;
my $userString = $row->[3];
        my @userNewRow = split(/,/,$userString);
        foreach(@userNewRow) {
            $row->[3] =~ s/.*/$_/;
            print Dumper $row;
            push @newRows, $row;
            print Dumper @newRows;
        }
```

Dumper Results are:

```
#comment: this is Dumper $row result of first run in loop
$VAR1 = [
          'Vehicle Factory',
          'D3',
          '2518, 1613, 1512, 1109, 912 bus, 712 bus, 613 Export',
          'ajj137035',
          'ddb255570',
          'mdb650204'
        ];
 #comment: this is the Dumper @newRows result of first run in loop
$VAR1 = [
          'Vehicle Factory',
          'D3',
          '2518, 1613, 1512, 1109, 912 bus, 712 bus, 613 Export',
          'ajj137035',
          'ddb255570',
          'mdb650204'
        ];
#comment: this is the Dumper $row result of 2nd run in loop 
$VAR1 = [
          'Vehicle Factory',
          'D3',
          '2518, 1613, 1512, 1109, 912 bus, 712 bus, 613 Export',
          ' mgp657301',
          'ddb255570',
          'mdb650204'
        ];
#comment: this is Dumper @newRows result of second run in loop 
the new value is inserted but the first value becomes same as new value
$VAR1 = [
          'Vehicle Factory',
          'D3',
          '2518, 1613, 1512, 1109, 912 bus, 712 bus, 613 Export',
          ' mgp657301',
          'ddb255570',
          'mdb650204'
        ];
$VAR2 = $VAR1;
```

Comment: changed the accepted answer as @aidan's provides a better way of doing the same or simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$row` is a ***reference*** to an array. You're repeatedly pushing this reference onto `@newRows` so `@newRows` will ultimately hold a set of pointers to the same thing. You need to make a copy of the array each time you push onto `@newRows`

e.g.

```
my @arr = (1, 2, 3);
my $ref_a = \@arr;
my $ref_b = \@arr;

$ref_a->[0] = "test";
print $ref_b->[0]; # prints "test";
```

p.s. you're over-complicating things:

```
my @row = ('Vehicle Factory', 'D3', '2518, ...', ...);
my @newRows = ();

for my $k (split /,\s*/, $row[3])
{
    push @newRows, [@row[0..2], $k, @row[4..$#row]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my $row = \@oneRow;
```

there's your problem. 
you are holding a reference to @oneRow
so that when you access the 4th element de-referenced from $row you are changing the value of @oneRow[3]

you've also pushed that reference into the list

instead of printing Dumper , just
    print @newRows

it will be elucidating (you will see the same pointer in there twice)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what do you want to get at the end. Below code will give you multidimential array

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl


use Data::Dumper;
use strict;
my @oneRow = ('Vehicle Factory',
        'D3',
        '2518, 1613, 1512, 1109, 912 bus, 712 bus, 613 Export',
        'ajj137035, mgp657301',
        'ddb255570',
        'mdb650204'
        );
my @newRows;
my $userString = $oneRow[3];
my @userNewRow = split(/,/,$userString);
foreach(@userNewRow) {
    $oneRow[3] =~ s/.*/$_/;
    push @newRows, [@oneRow];
}

print Dumper \@newRows;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'Vehicle Factory',
            'D3',
            '2518, 1613, 1512, 1109, 912 bus, 712 bus, 613 Export',
            'ajj137035',
            'ddb255570',
            'mdb650204'
          ],
          [
            'Vehicle Factory',
            'D3',
            '2518, 1613, 1512, 1109, 912 bus, 712 bus, 613 Export',
            ' mgp657301',
            'ddb255570',
            'mdb650204'
          ]
        ];
```

To just get a list then change your push to:

```
push @newRows, @oneRow;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'Vehicle Factory',
          'D3',
          '2518, 1613, 1512, 1109, 912 bus, 712 bus, 613 Export',
          'ajj137035',
          'ddb255570',
          'mdb650204',
          'Vehicle Factory',
          'D3',
          '2518, 1613, 1512, 1109, 912 bus, 712 bus, 613 Export',
          ' mgp657301',
          'ddb255570',
          'mdb650204'
        ];
```

I didn't understand the reason behind creating a reference, so I removed that part.

It helps if you also post your desired output next time :).

Comment: I added the reference to replicate the way Text::CSV reads the csv rows.